# multilevel linq query with left join

Tags: linq, left-join

Relations in my query:

[relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsIkx.png)

Here is my query with normal joins:

```
    var query = from myabonamenty in ArAbonamenty
            join nexotowary in Nexo_ARWAL.Asortymenty
            on myabonamenty.Nexo_towar equals nexotowary.Id
            join myklienci in ArKlienci
            on myabonamenty.Id_klient equals myklienci.Id_klient

            join nexoodbiorcy in Nexo_ARWAL.Podmioty
            on myklienci.Nexo_klient equals nexoodbiorcy.Id

            join nexonabywcy in Nexo_ARWAL.Podmioty
            on myklienci.Nexo_klient_do_faktur equals nexonabywcy.Id

            select new
            {
                abonament_id = myabonamenty.Id_abonament,
                towar=nexotowary.Nazwa,
                nabywca= nexonabywcy.NazwaSkrocona,
                odbiorca = nexoodbiorcy.NazwaSkrocona
            };
```

How can I make left joins in this query ( myklienci.Nexo_klient -> nexoodbiorcy.Id and myklienci.Nexo_klient_do_faktur->nexonabywcy.Id ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `into`/`from`/`in`/`DefaultIfEmpty()` for the ones that should be left joined:

```
var query = from myabonamenty in ArAbonamenty
        join nexotowary in Nexo_ARWAL.Asortymenty
        on myabonamenty.Nexo_towar equals nexotowary.Id
        join myklienci in ArKlienci
        on myabonamenty.Id_klient equals myklienci.Id_klient

        join nexoodbiorcy in Nexo_ARWAL.Podmioty
        on myklienci.Nexo_klient equals nexoodbiorcy.Id into nexoodbiorcyg
        from nexoodbiorcy in nexoodbiorcyg.DefaultIfEmpty()

        join nexonabywcy in Nexo_ARWAL.Podmioty
        on myklienci.Nexo_klient_do_faktur equals nexonabywcy.Id into nexonabywcyg
        from nexonabywcy in nexonabywcyg.DefaultIfEmpty()

        select new
        {
            abonament_id = myabonamenty.Id_abonament,
            towar=nexotowary.Nazwa,
            nabywca= nexonabywcy.NazwaSkrocona,
            odbiorca = nexoodbiorcy.NazwaSkrocona
        };
```

Depending on the database and LINQ version being used, you may also need to test for null or use the conditional operator for column references for range variables that may be empty:

```
        select new
        {
            abonament_id = myabonamenty.Id_abonament,
            towar=nexotowary.Nazwa,
            nabywca= nexonabywcy?.NazwaSkrocona,
            odbiorca = nexoodbiorcy?.NazwaSkrocona
        };
```

or

```
        select new
        {
            abonament_id = myabonamenty.Id_abonament,
            towar=nexotowary.Nazwa,
            nabywca= (nexonabywcy !=null ? nexonabywcy.NazwaSkrocona : null),
            odbiorca = (nexoodbiorcy != null ? nexoodbiorcy.NazwaSkrocona : null)
        };
```